# Unable to login

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

An apex page controller that exposes the site login functionality

```
global with sharing class SiteLoginController {
    global String username {get; set;}
    global String password {get; set;}


    global PageReference login() {
        System.debug('###'+ username);
        System.debug('###'+ password);

        return Site.login(username, password, '/apex/VerifyOTP');
    }

    global SiteLoginController () {}
}
```

Page Code

```
<apex:page id="loginPage" showHeader="false" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}"
                                                        controller="SiteLoginController">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputText value="{!userName}"/><br/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!password}" /><br/>

        <apex:commandButton value="Login" action="{!login}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I am not able to login after clicking login button

Comment: in your page use `apex:pagemessage` and check that. I am sure you are getting some error.